# Reusing code across React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a bunch of components with methods like these

```
class Header extends Component {

  sidebarToggle(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.body.classList.toggle('sidebar-hidden');
  }

  sidebarMinimize(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.body.classList.toggle('sidebar-minimized');
  }
}
```

I'd like to move this duplicate code to a function such as

```
function toggleBodyClass(className, e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.body.classList.toggle('sidebar-mobile-show');
}
```

Then refactor the functions above like so

```
  sidebarMinimize(e) {
    toggleBodyClass('sidebar-minimized', e);
  }
```

In the past, I would have used a mixin, but the React docs now discourage their use.

Should I just put this function in a regular JavaScript module and import it in the component modules, or is there a particular React construct for reusing code across components?

Comment: A small suggestion: It looks like you are using `<a/>` links as buttons (Since you're using all those `preventDefault`s). Maybe just convert them to `<button>` elements? Then you can leave out those preventDefault calls.

Comment: @Carl Edwards is correct, the Props Proxy Higher Order Component pattern is what the react docs recommend: https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html some more info: https://medium.com/@franleplant/react-higher-order-components-in-depth-cf9032ee6c3e

Answer (score 1):

You could make a [High Order Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) with those functions as so:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default function(ComposedComponent) {
  return class ExampleHOC extends Component {
    sidebarToggle(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      document.body.classList.toggle('sidebar-hidden');
    }

    sidebarMinimize(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      document.body.classList.toggle('sidebar-minimized');
    }

    render()
      return <ComposedComponent { ...this.props } />;
    }
  }  
}
```

Then take whatever component you wish to augment with those properties by wrapping them in the HOC:

```
ExampleHOC(Header);
```

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question properly. You should read it again.

Comment: what you mean it doesn't answer?? that is the React Way! the only problem of the code proposed is that there is not way for the underlying component to access the functionality of the hoc, but it is easy to solve

Comment: of course it is settings asign messing about with dom in react is rarely a good idea

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko read it again. OP wants to move the logic of changing an element classname and running event.preventDefault to a method to define it once, and then use it to define methods that implement such logic in a DRY way. Your answer is not a proper implementation of this.

Also he didn't ask for a 'React way', he asked if he should do it the standard JS way or if there's a better React-specific option for this case. There isn't.

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko What am I missing for the original component to access the functionality of the HOC?

Comment: I agree this is the correct place to use the Props Proxy HOC to define the functions once and make them re-useable and DRY

Comment: @DaniGuardiola As quoted by OP: "In the past, I would have used a mixin, but the React docs now discourage their use.". HOCs are the workaround for this. Dan Abramov himself even states this: https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750

Comment: @CarlEdwards OP wants to write ONE function that toggles a class and calls preventDefault on an event. Then he wants to use that abstract functionality to create other methods without repeating that logic. I don't know why that's so difficult to understand. This answer is not for this question. The fact that HOCs exist does not mean you need to or should use it in this case. This does NOT answer OP's question.

Comment: I would quote the relevant parts of the question to sustain my argument, but here's the thing: the whole question is the relevant part. I'm not trying to be annoying or cause a discussion, but it is a bit surprising to me that you don't get why you are not answering his question. It is pretty clear to me. Can you please read it again? Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I just put this function in a regular JavaScript module and import it in the component modules

Yes. That would be a pretty standard way to share code between JavaScript files. I don't believe you need to or should do anything React-related to achieve this.

**However**, it is important to understand that you shouldn't directly interact with the DOM **ever** from a React component. Thanks @ShubhamKhatri for the heads up.

Comment: One thing to understand here is that with React you should not directly modify the DOM

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri that is true, I'm gonna add it to my answer, however it is still true.

Comment: What should I do instead of `document.body.classList.toggle` to toggle a class?

Comment: @Dónal define the classes in your render method. For example: `<div className='someclass someotherclass {{ this.props.classXEnabled ? 'class-x' : '' }}></div>`. Then the method that you want to expose should toggle `this.props.classXEnabled` (true / false). This is just one example, but you should delegate the entire DOM rendering and manipulation processes to React to avoid headaches.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you are correct in putting the function in a regular JavaScript module and import it in the component modules.

Since a typical answer OOP answer would be to create another class extending React.Component adding that function. Then extend that class so every component you create will have that function but React doesn't want that.

One thing to verify that you are correct is in this pattern I believe.

https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Answer (score 0):

inherence solve your problem , create new class that extends `Component` and extend from your new class to share functionality and reduce the code

```
class SuperComponent extends Component
{
    sidebarToggle(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        document.body.classList.toggle('sidebar-hidden');
      }

      sidebarMinimize(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        document.body.classList.toggle('sidebar-minimized');
      }    
}

---------------------------------------------------------------------

class Home extends SuperComponent
{
    someMethod()
    {
        this.sidebarMinimize();
    }
}

class Main extends SuperComponent
{
    someMethod()
    {
        this.sidebarToggle();
    }
}
```

### Other Solution

create utils class and use it in your component

```
class UIUtiles
{
    static sidebarToggle(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        document.body.classList.toggle('sidebar-hidden');
    }

    static sidebarMinimize(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        document.body.classList.toggle('sidebar-minimized');
    }

}

class Home extends SuperComponent {
    someMethod(e) {
        UIUtiles.sidebarToggle(e);
        UIUtiles.sidebarMinimize(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I'd prefer a composition-based solution to one that relies on inheritance.

Comment: @Dónal checkout the other solution